# Slow Running MDX Query - running total

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

We're trying to create a calculated measure to do a running total of another Measure. Considering the amount of data is not huge, how can we make this query faster?

```
 WITH MEMBER [Measures].[X] AS aggregate 
 (
  {Null:[Transaction Date].CurrentMember},
  [Measures].[Transaction Amount]
 )
SELECT
 non empty {
  [Measures].[X]
 } ON columns
 , 
 non empty {
  ([Claim].[Claim Number].children* 
  [Transaction Date].[Hierarchy].[Day].&[2013-02-28T00:00:00]
  )
 } 
 ON rows
 FROM [ClaimsCube]
```

Comment: This article can help? http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2008/10/22/optimizing-mdx-aggregation-functions.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove "non empty"

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[X] AS aggregate 

(
  {Null:[Transaction Date].CurrentMember},
  [Measures].[Transaction Amount]
 )
SELECT
 {
  [Measures].[X]
 } ON columns
 , 
 {
  ([Claim].[Claim Number].children* 
  [Transaction Date].[Hierarchy].[Day].&[2013-02-28T00:00:00])
 } 
 ON rows
 FROM [ClaimsCube]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this will add millions of null value records and slow down the query even more.